# What font is used on Cote & Ciel?

Tags: font-identification

http://www.coteetciel.com/collections

What font is being used on this website? It's like a beautiful cross between ITC Avant Garde, and Helvetica. I love the way the lowercase L has a tail on it.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an advert. http://www.identifont.com/ is an amazingly useful tool for identifying fonts. I use it often and it hasn't been wrong yet. You will have to have a good enough sample of the font (enough letters) and some patience to get through the wizard. However you will almost always find the font that you're looking for. Worst case senario, you'll find a very close match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the typeface of Côte&Ciel is proprietary and I do not think it is available elsewhere.

If I were running a fashion company eager to stand out, I think that ordering a custom font based on logo (especially in just one style, like here) would be a rather considerable option.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is proprietary from https://www.swisstypefaces.com/imagine/

Comment: Please do not only answer with a link. Suppose the link is broken the answer is useless. Please add in own words how to solve the problem. Then the link can be a reference for further explanaition ... Welcome!